# OSDK with ROS: taking picture at waypoints

Tags: dji-sdk

I am implementing a mission on the DJI Matrice 100. I use the mission framework and need to automatically take picture at each mission waypoint. I check the waypoint action variable but I am not sure how I define the action so that one picture is taken when a waypoint is reached.
1. How do I check if a waypoint is reached ?
2. Is there a waypoint to set directly the picture taking event in the waypoint setting? for example waypoint->commandList = ....

Thank you in advance !

Comment: See [ask]. Things work better here if you show some code related to your question.

Answer (score 0):

For each waypoint that you want to take a photo add an action of type WaypointActionType.START_TAKE_PHOTO.

Like this:

waypoint.addAction(new WaypointAction(WaypointActionType.START_TAKE_PHOTO, 0)

Everything else is automatic after that.

Comment: The compiler is complaning with the message: _addAction_ is not member of _waypoint_
I think the syntax you gave is more likely from the mobile_sdk. I am using the Onboard SDK.

Comment: My mistake; I did not notice that you are using the Onboard ROS SDK; the example I included above is for the Mobile SDK.


For ROS take a look at the following, it should work relatively the same way but uses different naming conventions.

uint8_t DJI::OSDK::WayPointSettings::commandList[16]
          
uint16_t DJI::OSDK::WayPointSettings::commandParameter[16]

Comment: Yeah, I took a look on that. However, there is no indication on how to set those parameters in general, and in particular to set them so as to take a picture.